# Is a neutron star basically an isotope?

Tags: neutrons, neutron-stars, isotopes

Since a neutron star is basically just a vast amount of densely packed neutrons, I was wondering whether those neutrons form a single "atom" (of atomic number zero) or whether they are further apart and in a QFT-sense isolated?

Comment: The complex shell structure of neutron stars is driven by gravity and thermodynamics while the nuclear shell structure is a consequence of quantum mechanics. Unless you are also prepared to make a statement like "a planet is just a large molecule", then the answer is negative.

Comment: Please don't confound an atom with an isotope. They are related concepts but not the same.

Comment: @Gert I'm well aware of that, though my question's formulation probably doesn't convey that very well...

Comment: Related [miniature neutron stars](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136797/miniature-neutron-stars/136818#136818)

Comment: Atomic nuclei are held together by the strong force, neutron stars by gravity (you magically switch off gravity and they would explode). https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/735411/226902

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is a misnomer (at best) to characterize a neutron star as all neutrons. There are protons and electrons too.

Imagine compressing a bunch of regular matter at some point it requires less energy for a proton and electron to combine to form another neutron rather than for the electron to try to fill a very high energy state. That means there are so many electrons so as to fill all the states with energy up to the difference in energy of a neutron compared to a proton plus an electron. So those electrons stay around, as do an equal number of protons.

So if you want to think of it as an isotope, it wouldn't be a Z=0 isotope. And if it is so large you could even have protons entering one side and leaving another in a spacelike separated way, there is no clean sense where it is a single object with a certain Z. It is a system of many interacting parts.

Comment: Not to mention a crust of neutron-rich nuclei and a core that could contain something completely different.

Comment: And the crust that is made of a strongly ionized iron sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it is pure neutrons, I doubt that it can be called one single atom. Strong forces are short ranged and I don't think a macroscopic number of neutrons can form one single bound state. Instead they will form into many bound states each with a few neutrons.

Calling a neutron star a giant $Z=0$ atom would be like calling the earth, which is made of electrons, neutrons and protons, a giant atom with a giant $Z\neq 0$.